# Creating mongoid relation between has_one belongs_to objects raises an error

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have this relation:

```
class EmailType
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_one :job_status, :inverse_of => :email_type

class JobStatus
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :email_type, :inverse_of => :job_status
```

But when I try to create the relation between them I get an error. My example follows as far as I can see the same pattern as instructed on http://two.mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-1.html.

What makes this a mystery for me is that the error message displays `NameError: uninitialized constant JobStatu` and not `NameError: uninitialized constant JobStatus`...

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > e = EmailType.new
 => #<EmailType _id: 51eafe9183c3366282000001, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, type: nil, value: nil, from: nil, subject: nil, line_break: "\n", order_id_line: nil, order_id_regex: nil, mail_address_line: nil, mail_address_regex: nil, name_line: nil, name_regex: nil, user_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > j = JobStatus.new
 => #<JobStatus _id: 51eafea583c3366282000002, group_id: nil, name: nil, status: "new", error_msg: "", extra: {}, email_type_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > e.job_status = j
NameError: uninitialized constant JobStatu
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/metadata.rb:630:in `klass'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:54:in `klass'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/one.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:41:in `init'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/one.rb:20:in `initialize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `new'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `create_relation'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:269:in `block (2 levels) in setter'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:175:in `without_autobuild'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:263:in `block in setter'
from (irb):3
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'2.0.0-p247 :004 >
```

Just to be sure that I haven't mixed it up I have tried to do it the other way round:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > e = EmailType.new
 => #<EmailType _id: 51eaff9283c3365840000001, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, type: nil, value: nil, from: nil, subject: nil, line_break: "\n", order_id_line: nil, order_id_regex: nil, mail_address_line: nil, mail_address_regex: nil, name_line: nil, name_regex: nil, user_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > j = JobStatus.new
 => #<JobStatus _id: 51eaff9483c3365840000002, group_id: nil, name: nil, status: "new", error_msg: "", extra: {}, email_type_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > j.email_type = e
NameError: uninitialized constant JobStatu
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/metadata.rb:630:in `klass'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:54:in `klass'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/one.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:41:in `init'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/one.rb:20:in `initialize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `new'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `create_relation'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:269:in `block (2 levels) in setter'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:175:in `without_autobuild'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:263:in `block in setter'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/extensions/object.rb:104:in `do_or_do_not'
... 5 levels...
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:25:in `bind_one'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/in.rb:25:in `block in initialize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb:41:in `init'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/in.rb:23:in `initialize'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `new'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:44:in `create_relation'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:26:in `__build__'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:269:in `block (2 levels) in setter'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:175:in `without_autobuild'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mongoid-3.1.3/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:263:in `block in setter'
from (irb):3
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/christoffer-jorgensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'2.0.0-p247 :004 >
```

Comment: You're using ruby 2.0, and I don't have anything to check it with, but to help you, try a simpler name, likely something without an `S` in the end. You should be able to do it in reverse, so try `e.job_status = j`, and see if it works

Comment: You are right. The `s` was the problem. If you type that in as an answer then I will close the subject and reward the answer. Anoying that I can't use my original model name, but that's a lesson learned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ruby 2.0, and I don't have anything to check it with, but to help you, try a simpler name, likely something without an `S` in the end. `Statu` instead of `Status` means that mongoid tries to make it singluar, when searching for an specific model.

Your model sounds alright and you should be able to do it in reverse, so try `e.job_status = j`, and see if it truly works.

Answer (score 4):

It is a well-known Mongoid problem, [described here in the official documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#storage)

One possible workaround would be doing as suggested in the aforementioned document:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular("jobstatus", "jobstatus")
end
```

Or something close to that.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter solution:

```
has_one :job_status, :inverse_of => :email_type, :class_name => "JobStatus"
```

UPDATE:

@Ophion: I meant this should work:

```
class EmailType
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  has_one :job_status, :inverse_of => :email_type, :class_name => "JobStatus"
```

Explicitly add the class_name to the relationship so `Mongoid` will use it directly without having to singularize to get the Model name.

Comment: Can you expand on this some?